# Элементы массива

Tags: java, массивы

Я создал массив, присвоил каждому элементу значение, после, с помощью оператора println я попытался вывести на экран значение каждого элемента в массиве. Но результат получился следующим:

[I@2a139a55

В чем проблема?

```
int [] Int = new int [10]; 
Int [0] = 1;
Int [1] = 2;
Int [2] = 3;
Int [3] = 4;
Int [4] = 5;
Int [5] = 6;
Int [6] = 7;
Int [7] = 8;
Int [8] = 9;
Int [9] = 10;
System.out.println(Int);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Когда вы выводите строку в консоль при помощи `System.out.println` у аргумента вызывается метод `toString()` чтобы привести его к строке.

Для массива метод `toString()` приведет нас в метод `java.lang.Object.toString`, т.к. массив это тоже наследник класса `java.lang.Object`, а для того чтобы осознать что за строка выводится я советую вам ознакомится с первоисточником [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Для вывода всего содержимого массива в консоль используйте:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Для массива из массивов:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Для поэлементного вывода, начиная с jdk 1.8 можно использовать stream api:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

В версиях jdk до 1.7 при помощи foreach:

```
for(String str: arr) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

или обычного for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```